# I can get the next button to work but not the previous button. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a multi step form using jQuery. I have got the next button to work and show the next fieldset but I can't get the previous button to show the previous fieldset. I am very to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```HTML
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <h2>First Name</h2>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input
      type="button"
      name="next"
      class="next action-button"
      value="Next"
    />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Last Name</h2>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input
      type="button"
      name="prev"
      class="previous action-button"
      value="Previous"
    />
    <input
      type="button"
      name="next"
      class="next action-button"
      value="Next"
    />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Email</h2>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input
      type="button"
      name="previous"
      class="previous action-button"
      value="Previous"
    />
    <input
      type="button"
      name="submit"
      class="submit action-button"
      value="Submit"
    />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(function() {
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
    next_fs.show();
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
  previous_fs.show();
});
```

Comment: Your `$(.next)` is inside the doc ready, but the `$(.previous)` isn't - put them both in doc ready.

Comment: Check by adding this line above your `.click` line and checking console: `console.log($(".previous").length)` - if it's zero (0) then it can't find them at the time the code runs (they may be being added later, dynamically)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the $(.previous) to the doc ready but it still isn't working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to keep the two operations in a single method out of the `<fieldset>`. And use only two buttons to navigate. Then use an active class, for the `<fieldset>` to display.

The actions of the buttons would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next, .prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    current = $('fieldset.active');
    $(current).removeClass('active').hide();

    nextPrev = $(this).hasClass('next') ? $(current).next() : $(current).prev();

    $(nextPrev).addClass('active').show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".previous") is outside of $(document).ready so it's looking for the html tags before they are set. Move it inside the callback of $(document).ready and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes to toggle active state for various reasons, but in your case for the sake of simplicity.

Give your buttons `name` attribute a value of either `next` or `prev` so you can make use of these values in your direction logic.

When `.next` or `.previous` buttons are clicked, find the next target (using the next and prev directional values we set on the buttons earlier), remove the current active state and apply to new element.

```js
$(function() {
  var active = $('fieldset.active')
  $('.next, .previous').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).closest('fieldset')[this.name]();
    if (target.length) {
      active.removeClass('active');
      target.addClass('active');
      active = target;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  display: none;
}
fieldset.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
  <fieldset class="active">
    <h2>First Name</h2>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Last Name</h2>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="button" name="prev" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Email</h2>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="button" name="prev" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```